# Azure Data Factory Pipeline Alert Email Send Everytime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to send an email via an alert once an Azure Data Factory Pipeline has either finished successfully or failed. This is fairly simple to setup and I get the email once! However after the first time the email is sent it never sends again.

I understand that this is because the alert is in a fired state and will not send again unless this is changed. There is no way to change the state of the alert so the alert will never be triggered again.

Is there anyway to make it so the notification sends an email everytime the pipeline runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct , that once an alert is fired ( for what ever reason ) it needs to be deactivated and then only the other one can be fired again . My understanding is the alerts are configured for "not the happy path" and so the logic makes sense .

As it appears that just want to an email alert when your pipeline is executed . I suggest to use a logic App  to do that . You can execute this as the  last activity in the pipeline and call the logic app  from the pipeline . Configuring its is very easy .

Comment: Yes it will have to use a logic app because alerts don't work the way I want them to.